# Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Serialization.HybridRow.Result>

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-tables

Getting below error when trying to insert into CosmosDb. Document is being inserted but throwing this error. I'm using .net core 5.0, Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos 3.17.0.  Please advise.

Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Serialization.HybridRow.Result> Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Serialization.HybridRow.RecordIO.RecordIOStream.ReadRecordIOAsync(System.IO.Stream, System.Func`2<System.ReadOnlyMemory`1<Byte>,Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Serialization.HybridRow.Result>, System.Func`2<System.ReadOnlyMemory`1<Byte>,Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Serialization.HybridRow.Result>, Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Serialization.HybridRow.MemorySpanResizer`1)'

```
protected virtual CosmosClient _cosmosClient
    {
        get
        {
            var options = new CosmosClientOptions
            {
                SerializerOptions = new CosmosSerializationOptions
                {
                    IgnoreNullValues = true,
                    PropertyNamingPolicy = CosmosPropertyNamingPolicy.CamelCase
                },
                AllowBulkExecution = true
            };

            return new CosmosClient(_connectionString, options);
        }
    }

    protected Container _cosmosContainer
    {
        get => _cosmosClient.GetContainer(_databaseId, _containerId);
    }

protected async Task<T> CreateItemAsync<T>(string id, T model, PartitionKey partitionKey)
        {
            try
            {
                return await _cosmosContainer.CreateItemAsync(model, partitionKey);
            }
            catch (CosmosException ex)
            {
                LogCosmosDbError(ex);

                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please provide details about the version of SDK you're using and the relevant code where this throws. If it's the .NET SDK, you could open an issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues

Comment: I'm using .net core 5. Here is code snippet. 

`protected async Task<T> CreateItemAsync<T>(string id, T model, PartitionKey partitionKey)
        {
            try
            {
                return await _cosmosContainer.CreateItemAsync(model, partitionKey);
            }
            catch (CosmosException ex)
            {
                LogCosmosDbError(ex);

                throw;
            }
        }`

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code there, rather than as comment. This helps others see it. Also, please specify which version of the Comos .NET SDK you are using.

Comment: I've updated question to include code snippet. Using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos 3.17.0. Please take a look.

Comment: Removing AllowBulkExecution is working fine. I think it could be sdk issue? Setting AllowBulkExecution to true is throwing error "DocDBTrace Error: 0 : Exception during BatchAsyncBatcher: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Serialization.HybridRow.Result> 
"

Comment: @Raj Sir, according to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.cosmos.cosmosclientoptions?view=azure-dotnet-preview) on CosmosClientOptions, it's true that there isn't a option named AllowBulkExecution. So after removing the option, your code worked, right?

Comment: Did you recently update the SDK? It sounds like there is a mismatch on the DLLs in the project, have you tried cleaning up the `bin` folder and made sure the DLLs are updated on the deployment process?

Answer (score 0):

Reference: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/2292#issuecomment-796104041

Repeating what was stated in the comments for future reference: This is often related to DLL mismatching (older DLL for one or more dependencies).

It could be the project contains references to other projects with older versions of the SDK, in which case, make sure all the versions match.

It could also be an issue with your deployment process, maybe when the deployment happens, some DLLs are not getting overwritten, in which case, always make sure you are cleaning the `/bin` folder or updating all files with newer versions (some deployment processes might not update DLLs or the DLLs might be locked and currently in use).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with your same version, however, it turned out that the problem was caused by the dependencies installed in the CosmosDb Health Check from https://github.com/xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks I had version 5.03 of the health check and 3.17.1 of the Cosmos library and I was getting those errors.

When I removed the health check the issue went away.